# How to add 2 hours to a current time of excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have

```
29/06/2019  13:25:00
```

I want it to be

```
29/06/2019  15:25:00
```

I have 1000 rows, to do this action, I am using Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can simply do:

```
= A1+(2/24)
```

[image: example1]

If you want to use this formula for all the 1000 rows directly (assuming again the input column is A) you can simply adjust it like that:

```
= A1:A1000 + (2/24)
```

[image: example2]

Comment: It says you have a circular reference.

Comment: how? the formula is on B, the input value is on A. Don't put the formula in column A.

Comment: How do you add the formula to more than 1 row, lets say A1, A2 and A3

Comment: You have two options: either to drag it down to the desired cell or copy (ctrl+c), select all the rows you want to paste the formula in and then (paste options - formula).

Comment: Drag it down just copy paste the same value down. I have two different dates and times.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply this function to your cells. It will add 2 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

```
=A2+TIME(2,0,0)
```

Comment: What is A2 in here ? does it refer to something ?

Comment: A2 is hypotetically the cell in which you have the datetime value. Then you just have to drag the formula over all the cells.

Comment: That gave me 2:00 am back.

Comment: It says you have a circular reference.

Comment: You need to be sure to replace A2 with the cell in which you have the data to whihc you want to apply the formula.